# Version of internally published Addon keeps getting reset

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I have a published Google Slides Addon via the G Suite Marketplace SDK. After following the publishing guide everything looked great, until I wanted to bump the version number in the Google Cloud Console via my project's G Suite Market Place SDK Configuration tab.

I entered the number and hit "Save Changes", which put the new version life right away. However, it appears that a couple hours it will **always be reset to the same old version** (7 in my case). I bumped it again three times and have already tried to update the Chrome Webstore Draft, but it keeps being reset.

Checking the docs, I see no further steps required. I have also not found out yet when the reset occurs, it appears to be "over night" from a European timezone.

EDIT: what may also be relevant, the version in the Google Cloud Console does not automatically update when I publish to the Chrome Webstore. Instead, I manually put the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be fixed now.
Also the new publishing flow for GSM, which no longer requires to publish or do changes in the Chrome Web Store, is now live.